# Unable to match multiple digits in regex

Tags: regex, sed

I am simply trying to print 5 or 6 digit number present in each line.

cat file.txt

```
Random_something xyz ...64763
Random2 Some String abc-778986
Something something 676347
Random string without numbers
```

`cat file.txt | sed 's/^.*\([0-9]\{5,6\}\+\).*$/\1/'`

Current Output

```
64763
78986
76347
Random string without numbers
```

Expected Output

```
64763
778986
676347
```

The regex doesn't seem to work as intended with 6 digit numbers. It skips the first number of the 6 digit number for some reason and it prints the last line which I don't need as it doesn't contain any 5 or 6 digit number whatsoever

Comment: Every time you include `.*` in a regexp, you are inviting backtracking as greed takes over. Thus the regexp will start at the end and work backwards until it meets the minimum to succeed. In this case it will achieve this if it finds 5 digits. To make it match the first 5 or six digits it must also match the preceding character i.e. a non-digit. But remember the number may begin at the start of the line so it must match that too. e.g `sed -E 's/.*(^|[^0-9])([0-9]{5,6}).*/\2/' file` N.B. The `+` will effect the match and return multiples of 5 or 6 digits i.e. 5,6,10,11,12,,, digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` is a better for this with `-o` option that prints only matched string:

```sh
grep -Eo '[0-9]{5,6}' file

64763
778986
676347
```

`-E` is for enabling extended regex mode.

---

If you really want a `sed`, this should work:

```sh
sed -En 's/(^|.*[^0-9])([0-9]{5,6}).*/\2/p' file

64763
778986
676347
```

**Details:**

- `-n`: Suppress normal output
- `(^|.*[^0-9])`: Match start or anything that is followed by a non-digit
- `([0-9]{5,6})`: Match 5 or 6 digits in capture group #2
- `.*` Match remaining text
- `\2`: is replacement that puts matched digits back in replacement
- `/p` prints substituted text

Comment: Really appreciate the alternative solution , i am using sed regex primarily because apart from its direct usage mentioned in question , i also use it in a find command  ( -regextype sed -not -regex "regex-here" ) . i beleive i wont be able to do a grep exclude in find .

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`, you could try following. Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` and giving regex to match 5 to 6 digits in each line, if match is found then print the matched part.

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{5,6}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```